# How do I revert back to a previous build of Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2019, iis-express

How do I revert back to a previous build of Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition?

After updating to the latest build of VS2019 Community, IIS Express has become unusably slow with debugging and the update has caused a number of problems with existing projects. I need to revert back to 16.10.4.

How do I do this (the links on the MS site only have installers for Enterprise and Professional, not Community)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We provide older [installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/history#release-dates-and-build-numbers) for VS 2019 Enterprise, Professional and Build Tools, the [Community](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/servicing#support-options-for-enterprise-and-professional-customers) version is only supported on the recommended latest release of the latest minor version of VS.
To workaround this, please [fully uninstall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/remove-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) VS 2019 and download the Previous Professional edition that you want and run it, close the dialog (select workloads) that popups by default and click the '**Available**' tab from the installer, select the VS community 2019 version to install.

Comment: Thanks. Whatever the issue is that the update causes, this does fix it. I tried the update again but it does result in the same problem, so it is re-creatable. I've done the same procedure above again and it does resolve the issue, although this does mean I cannot update VS, which is obviously not good.